# Start RMDIR from Explorer to delete folders?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there a way to use the RMDIR (short form: RD) command (the one from CMD.exe) to delete folders from the File Explorer?

The default Explorer GUI dialog for deletion is orders of magnitude slower (18 seconds versus 4 in a recent test).

Comment: if you hit the system key, you can type the rd command... but you can't make Windows Explorer do that. Perhaps an alternative file explorer... https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-explorer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You absolutely can make the windows explorer do this.  And it is easy too.***

**DISCLAIMER:**
BE CAREFUL!! DOING STUFF LIKE THIS CAN HOSE WHOLE TREES!!
DO NOT DO THIS WITHOUT UAC ENABLED!! IT COULD BE ***REAL*** BAD!!

1. Open the registry editor
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\`
3. Create a new Key.. call it RMDIR (or whatever you want without spaces)
4. Edit the (default) string of this key to be whatever you want to show up on the right click of a folder.  Mine is `CMD Recursive Delete`.
5. Under your new key, create another key.  Call this one `command`
6. Edit the (default) string to `cmd.exe /s /c rmdir /s /q "%V" &&echo "%V" deleted&&pause`

```
What would I improve? (you ask)
```

You can change this to launch a batch file instead.  That batch file could
***VERIFY*** that you actually want to do this before clobbering stuff.

```
Other comments
```

- Edit the cmd.exe string to do whatever you want.  I gave you the way that I would do it.
- This will delete anything you can delete from a normal (non-elevated) command prompt using `rd /s /q`
- I DO know how to do this elevated but that is a lesson for the reader to figure out (because it is dangerous).

Comment: Does not work at all. Is a reboot needed or something?

Comment: PS: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61022058/822870) suggests it is a bug in Windows 10 ver 1909 which I have...

Comment: Sorry, "pilot error". It works.

Comment: FYI: I removed the /q option from rmdir, so it asks y/n if the user wants to delete or not. A bit awkward when multiple folders are selected (a new window is opened for each, asking y/n), but...